# How to scrape data using google api

Tags: python, google-api, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

```
import requests

def search(query, pages=4, rsz=8):
    url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
    params = {
        'v': 1.0,     # Version
        'q': query,   # Query string
        'rsz': rsz,   # Result set size - max 8
    }

    for s in range(0, pages*rsz+1, rsz):
        params['start'] = s
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
        for result in r.json()['responseData']['results']:
            yield result
```

At first 2,3 attempts it is retrieving all required pages, but after 2,3 attempts it is not getting any result. It is returning "None" or []. Is google blocking my IP after few attempts? Any solution?

Comment: check `r.status_code` and `r.text`. Maybe there is any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was sorted out using requests and BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests, import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
payload = { 'q' : strToSearch, 'start' : str(start), 'num' : str(num) }
r = requests.get( url,params = payload, auth=('user', 'pass')) 
subSoup = BeautifulSoup( subR.text, 'html.parser' )
text = soup.get_text(separator=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this would work or not, but the only way to avoid getting blocked by sites that do not encourage Scraping is to use proxy while retrieving web pages.
Please check how proxy can be used in your code.