# Python BeautifulSoup : google search page scraping with specific text not giving any Title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am completely new to Web Scraping using Python BeautifulSoup. Using SO and other blogs I have tried to build my first piece of code.

**Objective:** Given a string as input, the code will search in https://www.google.com and get the search results with following information:

1. Title
2. Brief Description
3. Link

Say I want to search "Core Banking Solution by Accenture". To do so :

```
search_str ='Core Banking Solution Accenture'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + search_str
page  = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')
for node in soup.find_all('a'):
   print("Inner Text : {}".format(node.text))
   for h in soup.find_all('h3'):
      print("Title : {}".format(h.text)
   print("Link :{}".format(node.get('href'))
```

I am getting an error for `title`.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Clearly, it is not getting any title object from `soup.find_all('a')`.

Question: What trick I have to apply here to get the title? Does `soup.find_all('a') really contains any` title` tag? What I am missing here?

Update: Based on the suggestions received, I have updated code piece. Now it is working. Although need to check the results in details.

Comment: "a" tag contains the hyperlinks. To find the title, you can just use `str(soup.title)`

Comment: Inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @balmy: Understood and thats an typo. Meanwhile, can you please throw some lights on the OP?

Comment: Two identical typos, to be precise. Do any searching? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663434/how-to-scrape-data-using-google-api and many other results

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `node.get("title")` returns `None`, as there is no title-attribute in the a-tag. This causes an error when accessing the .text-attribute. Instead, we may examine the HTML to figure out which part of the tag constitutes the title. See the example below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ''' 
<a href="https://html.com/attributes/a-title">
    <br>
    <h3>When To Use A Title In HTML</h3>
    <div>
        <cite role="text">https://html.com
            <span role="text"> › attributes › a-title</span>
        </cite>
    </div>
</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.get("title")) # prints None
    print(tag.h3.text) # prints "When To Use A Title In HTML"
```

In this search result, the title is found in the contents of the h3-tag. We can extract it using tag.h3.text. The browser devtools are a great resource when trying to figure out how to navigate the tags.